Unions and little-endiannes in c++
I am playing with unions in C++.
union T
{
    int a;
    char ch;
    short b;
};

int main()
{
    T obj;
    obj.a = 0x12345678;
    std::cout << std::hex << obj.a << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)obj.ch << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::hex << obj.b << std::endl;
}

As my processor is little-endian (I think), I expect the bytes to be saved in the memory in the following order: 78 56 34 12 (starting from the least significant). Why do I get 56 78 when I print obj.b, though? What's happening? If my system was big-endian, obj.ch would be 12, but it's 78. What am I missing? I expected 78 56.

obj.b is a short. Its stored as 7856 but its value is 5678.

@tkausl, I am not sure I understand why its value is 5678. 0x7856 isn't that number in decimal, I think.

I meant 5678 hex, not decimal.

This is C++ stop playing with (untagged) unions, really run away from them as fast as you can. Last thing you want to do is to use unions for type punning. This might work in "C" but it is undefined behavior in C++. Read about C++'s std::variant and even that is not to be used for type punning, For that use C++20's std::bitcast or memcpy.

Also see C++'s core guidelines : [P.4: Ideally, a program should be statically type safe](P.4: Ideally, a program should be statically type safe) and rules 180-183, specially C.183: Don’t use a union for type punning

The short is also stored as little-endian.

Side note: nothing in this code needs the extra stuff that std::endl does. Use '\n' to end a line unless you have a good reason not to.

"Why do I get 56 78 when I print obj.b, though?" -- Let's turn this question around and start from your output. Given that "my processor is little-endian (I think)", if you were to write short b = 0x5678; how would you expect this to be stored?

  M0   M1   M2   M3
+----+----+----+----+
| 78 | 56 | 34 | 12 |  int a = 0x12345678
+----+----+----+----+
|         |
|         |
+----+----+
| 78 | 56 |  short b = 0x5678
+----+----+
|    |
|    |
+----+
| 78 |  char ch = 0x78
+----+

